# WCF CallBack implementation

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-callbacks

Im having hard time to understand the advantages of callback on the basic way of making our client to be a service too and our service to be a client too.

Comment: It would be a lot better to phrase your question as a question.

Comment: Im looking for advantages for using CallBack insted of simple client-service. Im sory for any confusion I made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give you one big advantage. We have an application that involves a client (WPF) and a Windows service. Normally the client calls the service (via WCF) to retrieve and/or save data etc. But, there are times we want the service to send the client a message, to notify the client it needs to perform a certain action (like shutdown or display a message to the user - could be anything). A callback is perfect for this.

Comment: Then why shouldnt I make the client a service and call the method? Why I need to use "Callback"-dealing with duplex, ServiceInstance, ..?

Comment: This totally depends on the type of application you are creating. For us, we've got multiple clients hitting our service. There are times we want our service to send a message to active clients. We already have the client talking to our service via WCF. Adding callback functionality was pretty trivial.

Comment: Randy Minder Thanks. I have personal thing to ask you. I can see you work as a programer, how does math helps you to solve problems? only in methods or in wcf designing too? I have always been curious about this subject.

Comment: Math doesn't help me much at all. I will sometimes use basic algebra but that is somewhat rare.

Comment: In what feild in programming, the math have a part?